# Matrices, Transition matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $B:= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & -\lambda\end{bmatrix} $

I need to diagonalise it and work out the transition matrix.

I have worked out that the eigenvalues are $ \mu_± = \frac{-\lambda ± \sqrt{\lambda^2-4}}{2} $
hence the diagonal matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2-4}}{2} & 0\\0 & \frac{-\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2-4}}{2}\end{bmatrix} $

I cant seem to work out the eigenvectors for the corresponding eigenvalues, therefore cant construct the transition matrix.

Comment: Do you really need the eigenvectors to get the transition matrix?

Comment: @JefLaga Isn't the transition matrix constructed from the eigenvectors?

Comment: Note that $\lambda = \pm 2$, the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write
$$
B - \mu_+ I = \pmatrix{-\mu_+ & 1\\-1&1/\mu_+}\\
B - \mu_- I = \pmatrix{-\mu_- & 1\\-1 & 1/\mu_-}
$$
from there it, should be easy to determine the eigenvectors in terms of $\mu_{\pm}$.

---

The clever algebra I mentioned: for example,
$$
- \mu_+ - \lambda = \\
\frac{\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2} - \lambda = \\
\frac{-\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2} = \mu_- = \\
\frac{-\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{2}
\frac{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}}{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}} =\\
\frac 12 \frac{\lambda^2 - (\sqrt{\lambda^2  - 4})^2}{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}} = \\
\frac{2}{-\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 4}} = 1/\mu_+
$$

Comment: on the RHS, in the bottom right of each matrix, how did you get that value, as i got $-\lambda ± \mu_± $

Comment: You can simplify the expression with some clever algebra. The easier method, however, is to remember that the matrix has to be singular, which in this case implies that one row is a multiple of the other.

Comment: could you possibly show the clever algebra, as i attempted it several times and couldn't work it out

Comment: Thank you that makes full sense, however, how do i use this to solve for eigenvectors, i keep spinning around a circle and getting $x=x$ where $x$ corresponds to the first value in the eigenvector

Comment: Not sure where you're having trouble. However, try $$\pmatrix{1\\ \mu_+}$$